# Cron expression that runs every 5 minutes from 1:30 am - 6:00 am

Tags: cron

I'm looking to run a job at these very specific times.

Can this even be done in one expression?

Comment: This type of question has been frequently asked and answered, can I suggest that before asking the question, you look into the archives just a tinnie bit more?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd need two expressions to deal with the start on the half hour:

```
30-55/5 1 * * *     user    command
*/5 2-5 * * *       user    command
```